# error while trying to add JPA to JSF/glassfish project

Tags: java, jsf, jpa, glassfish

I get the following error:

WELD-000049 Unable to invoke public void bean.Kwetterbean.loadContent() on bean.Kwetterbean@308f71d

What files are needed to help me?

Apparantly I can not ad the entire stack because then it is to much code:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049 Unable to invoke public void bean.Kwetterbean.loadContent() on bean.Kwetterbean@308f71d
at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:91)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.postConstruct(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:73)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.postConstruct(BasicInjectionTarget.java:95)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.postConstruct(BeanInjectionTarget.java:65)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:161)
at org.jboss.weld.context.ForwardingContextual.create(ForwardingContextual.java:27)
at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:103)
at org.jboss.weld.context.PassivatingContextWrapper$AbstractPassivatingContextWrapper.get(PassivatingContextWrapper.java:64)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:93)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:79)
at bean.Kwetterbean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getGebruiker(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:291)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:988)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1249)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewParameter.processValidators(UIViewParameter.java:278)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1258)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1258)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1195)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:89)
... 64 more



Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at bean.Kwetterbean.loadContent(Kwetterbean.java:195)
... 69 more
```

Comment: I have a nagging feeling that this is not the entire stacktrace; I'm missing a root cause

Comment: I added some more of the stacktrace, but if I add more, I need to add more text to. Must I add all text saying "Caused by"?

Comment: No, you already have your reason. Line 195 of your Kwetterbean throws a NullPointerException. Now you need to go figure out why. Java is so nice, it tells you exactly what the problem is. All you have to do, is listen.

Comment: @PostConstruct 
    public void loadContent() {
        user = kwet.findByName(gebruiker);
        name = user.getName();

Comment: the line is the name=user.getName(); this line works fine when I don't use JPA. so I need to find the problem in the JPA part of my code?

Comment: You need to figure out why that findByName() returns a null-value, yes.

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that one beans is opened before the other. The one with @Startup schould be the first of the 2. Is that not done automatly?